# Developing Smart JavaScript Dropdown Menus

Tags: javascript, html

```js
            function exploreFunction() {
                document.getElementById("explore").classList.toggle("show");
            }
            
            window.onclick = function(event) {
                if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
                var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        

        
            function communityFunction() {
                document.getElementById("community").classList.toggle("show");
            }
            
            window.onclick = function(event) {
                if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
                var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        

        
            function storeFunction() {
                document.getElementById("marketplace").classList.toggle("show");
            }
            
            window.onclick = function(event) {
                if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
                var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                    }
                }
                }
            }
```

```css
.nav-bottom {
        text-align:right;
        margin:1rem 1rem 0 0;
        display:none;
        display:inline-block;
        position: relative;
        width:100%;
        padding-bottom:1rem;
    }

    .nav-bottom-link {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        font-size:15px;
        margin-left:2.5rem;
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#111;
        font-weight:700;
        background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
        border:none;
        padding-bottom:.5rem;
        cursor:pointer;
    }

    .nav-bottom-link:hover {
        color:#cc0000;
        transition:.2s;
    }
            
    .fa-angle-down {
        margin: 0 0 3px 3px;
        font-size:1.65rem;
      }

    .dropdown-content {
        display:none;
        position:fixed;
        top:60px;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:81vh;
        background-color:rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.8);
    }

    .show {
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-top:0;">
    <div class="col-md">
       <div class="nav-bottom">
           <button onclick="exploreFunction()" class="nav-bottom-link dropbtn">Explore <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></button>

           <div id="explore" class="dropdown-content"></div>

            <button onclick="communityFunction()" class="nav-bottom-link dropbtn">Community <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></button>

            <div id="community" class="dropdown-content"></div>

            <button onclick="storeFunction()" class="nav-bottom-link dropbtn">Marketplace <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></button>

            <div id="marketplace" class="dropdown-content"></div>
         </div>                
       </div>
     </div>
```

I am creating three dropdown menus for a website (using the 3 javascript functions above). As I have it now when you click a button the function runs to "show" the dropdown menu specific to that button. However, unless I click outside of the dropdown before clicking on the next button, the two dropdowns overlap. Essentially, I want the function to close the previous dropdown if it is open before showing the next.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your relevant HTML and CSS and create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to work with? At the moment there is nothing we can do with what you've provided us.

Comment: Code Snippet Added! :)

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution: You can find the element that has the 'show' class and remove it.

i.e.

`document.querySelector('.show').classList.remove('show')`

You can add this to your button handlers, BEFORE the line of code that adds the show class to the menu you want to show.

i.e.

`function storeFunction() {
        document.querySelector('.show').classList.remove('show');        document.getElementById("marketplace").classList.toggle("show");
            }`

Comment: Thank KaeyangTheG, I added this to the function a now the menu doesn't show at all when I click on the buttons. I understand the logic, but just not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: I used getElementById rather than querySelector and that seems to work.